# positioning problem with uisplitviewcontroller in left view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

i got a little problem, when launching my splitview in landscape, there is a little black space above my left view controller:
[image]

after rotating my ipad to portrait and switching back to landscape, the space is gone.

if i load the uitableviewcontroller directly into the left view, and not in a navigationcontroller, it works fine:
[image]

any ideas why this is happening ??

```
// Produkte
    self.produkteMainTableVC = [[produkteMainTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *produkteMainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.produkteMainTableVC];
    self.produkteDetailVC = [[produkteDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"produkteDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.produkteSplitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

    self.produkteSplitVC.delegate = self.produkteDetailVC;
    self.produkteMainTableVC.produkteDetailVC = produkteDetailVC;
    [self.produkteSplitVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:produkteMainNavigationController,self.produkteDetailVC,nil]];
```

thanks for all help!

edit:
its exactly 20px like the statusbar. does that help anyone?

edit2:

doing something like this:

```
if(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y >= 20.0) {

        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.x, 0.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    }
```

results that:
[image]

a little improvement i would say. but i have no idea how to stick my tableview underneath the navigationbar.

Comment: did you end up with any working solution for this?

Comment: no. decided to use a split view without a tabbar and reviced my navigation concept

Comment: I figured out a way to achieve this; see my answer, below.  The trick was not to use a standard UITabViewController and instead create my own.  Pretty easy since UITabViewController is fairly basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UINavigationController has a nasty habit of shifting its contents down by 20px, depending where you place it.  I'm guessing it's doing it here because your split view controller is inside of a tabbar controller, and Apple has not blessed this type of arrangement.

Comment: but it works ;) do you think apple will approve this? don't know if there are appications like that out there. do you have an idea how to avoid this special behavior ?

Comment: It would probably be approved if you can figure out how to overcome the 20px problem.  Though I've tried to do so in a different situation and gave up.

Comment: You're on the same track that I was.  I don't remember what all the issues were, but it seemed that any time I tried to nudge something one way, something else would pop out.  And it's complicated by the fact that the layout behaves differently when you rotate to landscape and then back to portrait.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old topic but maybe it'll help other people...

I had the same issue (with the same configuration : splitview in tabbar).
This property solved it !

```
[self.splitViewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

Comment: thanks for this late comment. sure, it will probably help some people!

Comment: @Funyafunya I was like going to mad at this issue and I almost hit the wall. But surely your late comment just saved me right at this moment. From now on, I will too always post my correct known solutions/experiences even if it's too late:) Thanks buddy.

Comment: It's never too late to add something to a SO question. You're not just answering the OP's question, you're answering the question of hundreds of other developers who come across this thread in future. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same issue, with out a resolution. The only thing I've noticed is this does NOT happen when the master does not include a UINavigationController as its root.

Anyone figure a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, and it seems to work fine.

I created my own custom tab-view controller, derived from `UIViewController`.  In `viewDidLoad` I add a `UITabBar` to the bottom of the view and set the delegate to myself so I can handle tab changes.  (I return this `UITabBar` as the `rotatingFooterView`)  Tab changes result in swapping the current view controller, just like a real `UITabBarController`.  When swapping view controllers (sometimes a `UISplitViewController`, hosting a `UINavigationController` in the master view), I add and position the view-controller's view within my view, above the `UITabBar`.  I'm also careful to forward viewWill/DidAppear/Disappear calls to the current view controller, as well as each of the will/didRotate messages.

Comment: do you have something like a sample project for sharing with us?

Answer (score 0):

seems that this problem occurs from iOS 7.0. Setting the frame of `UINavigationBar` in some cases doesn't work. I think this can solve your problem :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width,
                                                          self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height);
    }
```

This code should be called only once (for example in `- (void)viewDidLoad` ). 
In my case it works for all device orientation.